# How to scrape html tags spread over multiple lines in python?

Tags: python, scripting, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a webpage in python. I was able to easily get the results for tags which were on a single line, but for tags spread over multiple lines, my code cannot retrieve anything.

In the HTML source single line tags are present as:

```
<td><span class="facultyName">John Matthew Falletta, MD</span>
```

and multiple line tags are present as:

```
<td><span class="label">Division:</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                  </td><td>Hematology/Oncology</td>
```

Here is what I wrote:

```
patFinderFullname = re.compile('<span class="facultyName">(.*)</span>')

fullname = re.findall(patFinderFullname,webpage)         #works fine

patFinderDivision = re.compile('<span class="label">Division:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>(.*)</td>')

division = re.findall(patFinderDivision,webpage)       #doesn't work
```

Here my webpage variable contains the url which has to be scraped.  Can someone point out, what I am missing, or where I am wrong?

Comment: Don't post an image of text.  Post the text so someone can cut/paste if they want to work with it.

Comment: My text contains html tags, it is automatically being formatted by the editior during posting.

Comment: The source of your post contains a .jpg.

Comment: It was being formatted, that's why I posted a jpg, so that it remains exactly what I wrote.

Comment: Use Ctrl-K to mark the text as code and it won't format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend you use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).
It is a Python library for parsing HTML documents.

P.s: If you want to stick with your own code, use \s* to skip white spaces in regex.

```
patFinderDivision = re.compile('<span class="label">Division:</span>\s*&nbsp;&nbsp;\s*</td><td>(.*)</td>')
```

Comment: Can you suggest how to read text from multiple line tags,like in my example I want "Hematology/Oncology" to be extracted in the variable division.

Comment: try \s+ to avoid the white spaces in regex

Comment: I got it correct for division but now Address field is baffling me :<td><span class="label">Address:</span></td><td>Box 2991<br>DUMC<br>Durham, NC &nbsp;27710    </td>      Is this the correct regex for this patFinderAddress = re.compile(' <span class="label">Address:</span>\s+(.*)\s+</td>')

Comment: Posting the code as a comment is not a good idea. I cannot see the new lines this way so that I can tell you where to put the "\s*". In the case of address it is a bit different as you want to extract multiple chunks of data. you may want to look into re.search and group.

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889996/error-in-regex-formulation-for-web-scraping-in-python.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a sample to what kind of regexp you'd need to pull out the division:

```
re.compile('<span class="label">Division:</span>\s*&nbsp;&nbsp;\s*</td><td>(.*?)</td>')
```

Comment: [code]<td><span class="label">Phone:</span></td><td>
 (919)
 668-5111<br>
</td> [/code]. Can you help me with the regex code for this. Is  this correct [code]patFinderPhone = re.compile('<span class="label">Phone:</span></td><td>\s+(.*)\s+<br>')[/code]

Comment: You're mostly there - except you're using \s+ after the number which implies that there must be atleast one whitespace. When you're not sure about the existence of whitespace - use \s*:

    re.compile('<span class="label">Phone:</span></td><td>\s*(.*?)\s*<br>')

Comment: Still not coming. Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889996/error-in-regex-formulation-for-web-scraping-in-python .